# Vue access nested array objects

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

As my array consists of multiple data, it was difficult to upload all of them. So I have uploaded an image of my array and objects below.

[image: Array Nested Object]

**View**

```
<draggable :list="reservation.Reservation_people" class="list-group" draggable=".item" group="a">
   <div class="list-group-item item" v-for="element in reservation.Reservation_people" :key="element.name">
     <p>{{element.Person.first_name}}</p> /** Prints out Person.first_name **/

     /** is there a way to fetch Player_minors first_name="Sanu" as a separate entity 
under element.Person.first_name. So that it can drag Person.first_name and 
Player_minors.first_name separately; **/

    </div>
</draggable>
```

Is there a way to fetch Player_minors first_name="Sanu" as a separate entity under element.Person.first_name. So that it can drag Person.first_name and Player_minors.first_name separately?

Using `element.Person.first_name` prints out **San**. But if I use `{{element.Person.Player.Player_minors.first_name}}` it does not print out anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Player.player_minors` is an array, so you can't do `Player.player_minors.first_name`.

If you want to print *the first* player_minor name, you could do

```js
{{ element.Person.Player.player_minors[0].first_name }}
```

If you want to print *all* of the player_minor names, you would have to use a nested `v-for`.

```html
<div class="list-group-item item" v-for="element in reservation.Reservation_people" :key="element.name">
     <p>{{element.Person.first_name}}</p> /** Prints out Person.first_name **/

     <p
        v-for="player_minor in element.Person.Player.player_minors" 
        :key="player_minor.id">
          {{player_minor.first_name}}
     </p>

</div>
```

Comment: it prints out the minor when I used v-for="player_minor in element.Person.Player.Player_minors" but when I drag {{element.Person.first_name}} it drags {{player_minor.first_name}} as well. Is there a way to solve that ?